# Can't access selected value from drop-down menu

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, jspx

I have a problem with drop down list on my jspx page. I see variable values ​​are displayed on the page, but i can't get the selected value. The input string is empty, so i get

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

in this line:

```
int idRoom = Integer.parseInt(requestInformation.getRequestParameter("idRoom"));
```

Here is my jspx page:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
version="2.0">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=Utf-8"/>
<html>
    <head>
    <title><fmt:message bundle="${loc}" key="page.newOrders"/></title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:directive.include file="/jsp/header.jspx"/>
<h2><fmt:message bundle="${loc}" key="label.greeting"/>, ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}.</h2>
        <table cellspacing="15">
        <tr>                
        <td align="center"><b><fmt:message bundle="${loc}" key="field.idOrder"/>:</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b><fmt:message bundle="${loc}" key="field.availableRooms"/>:</b></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${orderList}" var="cell">
        <tr>                                                
            <td align="center">${cell.id}</td>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${cell.roomList == null}">
                        <td align="center"><fmt:message bundle="${loc}" key="message.noRooms"/></td>
                    <td></td>                               
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                <form action="Controller" method="get" id="acceptForm">
                    <td align="center">
                            <select name="selectedRoom">
                            <c:forEach items="${cell.roomList}" var="room">
                            <option value="${room.id}">${room.id}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <fmt:message bundle="${loc}" key="button.accept" var="accept"/>
                    <a href="Controller?command=accept&amp;idOrder=${cell.id}&amp;idRoom=${selectedRoom}" onclick="document.getElementById('acceptForm').submit()">${accept}</a>                                  
                    </td>                                                   
                </form>                                                         
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>          
                <td align="center">
                <fmt:message bundle="${loc}" key="message.rejectOrder" var="reject"/>
                    <c:url value="Controller" var="rejectUrl">
                        <c:param name="command" value="reject"/>
                    <c:param name="idOrder" value="${cell.id}"/>
                </c:url>
                    <a href="${rejectUrl}" onClick="return window.confirm('${reject}')">
                        <fmt:message bundle="${loc}" key="button.reject"/>
                    </a>
            </td>                               
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
    </table>            
    <jsp:directive.include file="/jsp/footer.jspx"/>
    </body>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try it like:

```
int idRoom = Integer.parseInt(requestInformation.getRequestParameter("idRoom").toString());
```

and tell if this solves your problem or not?

Also, looking into your exception, it seems like that parameter contains an empty string. Either you are not calling the right parameter, or check for case sensitivity...

Or use Firebug to ensure that request contains parameter with the name idRoom

Thanks...

Mr.777

Comment: It doesn't matter, `requestInformation.getRequestParameter("idRoom")` already returns `String`. And i know the `String` is empty, my question is why is it empty and how can i fix that.

Comment: I told you, you need to debug it.... See if the parameter name is correct, parameter value is in the form and it's properly sent.

Comment: In Firebug I see this: `<a href="Controller?command=accept&idOrder=8&idRoom="`. `idRoom` value is not passed to the command.

Comment: If i use simple `<input name="command" type="hidden" value="accept"/>         <input type="submit" value="accept"/>` i can get `idRoom` value in command. But when i try to transmit value using `<a href ...>` i get empty String.

Comment: How did you generate href? Do you generate it dynamically or it has static value for idRoom?

Comment: Dynamically - user choose it from drop down select menu.